# Spark job callback

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataproc

Maybe you can help me with my problem 
I start spark job on google-dataproc through API. This job writes results on the google data storage. 
When it will be finished I want to get a callback to my application. 
Do you know any way to get it? I don't want to track job status through API each time.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There isn't a callback mechanism. Any API will require either polling or hanging get calls + retries. However, what is your end goal? What do you want to do with the callback as there may be other options.

Comment: I am imagining an application that invoke Spark jobs as required, but it needs to wait for the results for taking decision. Could confirm or clarify giving an example? There may be some alternatives depending on what exactly you want to do.

Comment: @tix
Thanks for your feedback, guys.
I want to get a callback to know about finishing of operation. Then I can get data processed by spark

Comment: Then polling is the way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll agree that it would be nice if there was to either wait for or get a callback for when operations such as VM creation, cluster creation, job completion, etc finish. Out of curiosity, are you using one of the api clients (like [google-cloud-java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-clients/google-cloud-dataproc)), or are you using the REST API directly?

In the mean time, there are a couple of workarounds that come to mind:

1) Google Cloud Storage (GCS) callbacks

GCS can trigger callbacks (either [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage) or [PubSub notifications](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications)) when you create files. You can create an file at the end of your Spark job, which will then trigger a notification. Or, just add a trigger for when you put an output file on GCS.

If you're modifying the job anyway, you could also just have the Spark job call back directly to your application when it's done.

2) Use the [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/jobs/) command line tool (probably not the best choice for web servers)

gcloud already waits for jobs to complete. You can either use `gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark ...` to submit and wait for a new job to finish, or `gcloud dataproc jobs wait <jobid>` to wait for an in-progress job to finish.

That being said, if you're purely looking for a callback for choosing whether to run another job, consider using [Apache Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/) + [Cloud Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer/).

In general, the more you tell us about what you're trying to accomplish, we can help you better :)

Comment: "If you're modifying the job anyway, you could also just have the Spark job call back directly to your application when it's done. " -> The job might fail due to other reasons in the code before this section of code is run for callback, how do you suggest tracking that failure without polling?